# generate different exceptions from soap in c#

Tags: c#, java, soap, code-generation

we have a server which is written in java and provide some webservices... some of them throws custom exceptions, which server sends to user application.

Application is written in C#. I would like to be able to catch these exception in user application and throw them again.

I know that it is possible to throw general soap exception bu i would like to throw kind of same exception as on server.

I know how to generate wsdl file and xsd files for services, there are described also these exceptions, if I use xsd.exe I know how to generate a c# classes which are similar to the exceptions, but they are not exceptions :(

So I am not sure how to generate exceptions instead and how to interpret soap fault code as exception of right type...

example of fault code in soap:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>some info</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Fault occurred while processing.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns1:MyException xmlns:ns1="http://xxx/">
               <den xsi:type="ns2:day" xmlns:ns2="http://xxx/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">THURSDAY</den>
            </ns1:MyException>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any ideas? Did you do something like this before...? It is even possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.
In Java just write throws MyException after your webservice method.
Then generate wsdl and xsd.
From wsdl and xsd generate c# code by svcutils.exe

You can use your webservice and catch faults like:

```
FaultException<MyException> ex
```

where ex will have all properties from MyException in detail.